# XAML can't find namespace for validating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I wrote a Validation Rule, and wrote the style and everything in the XML. I am getting one small problem that I cannot understand and its that the XAML says the namespace doesn't exist. At the XAML header I added this:

```
xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:New_ComplaintManager.ViewModels"
```

And in my textbox I have this:

```
validators:RequiredFields ErrorMessage="username is required." />
```

Yet XAML says:

```
The tag 'RequiredFields' does not exist in XML namespace 
'clr-namespace:New_ComplaintManager.ViewModels'.
```

But the ViewModel contains this:

```
namespace New_ComplaintManager.ViewModels
{
class RequiredField
{
    public class RequiredFields : ValidationRule
```

So I am stuck. I even read this guide: [XAML MSDN Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to no avail.

Comment: when working with WPF, try to avoid nested classes, because in some cases, we cannot reference the inmost class easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make changes as below

```
namespace New_ComplaintManager.ViewModels
{
  public class RequiredFields : ValidationRule
  {

  }

}
```

Please remove Below lines

```
class RequiredField
```

Need of removing above class because it is not defined publicly and your RequiredFields class will not be known to outside.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashok Rathold already answered - I add my 2 cents: Try to use full declaration as in

```
xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:clr-namespace:New_ComplaintManager.ViewModels;assembly=your_assembly"
```